# Локализация кнопки Done

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios

Есть ли возможность где-то взять строки, которые используются для локализации системной кнопки Done в `UINavigationBar`?

В данный момент я вынуждена использовать `UINavigationBar` только из-за того, что он поддерживает  локализацию для кнопки `Done`, но по сути никакой навигации в приложении нет и Done выполняет кастомную функцию. Я бы хотела использовать свою собственную view с локализированной кнопкой `Done`, если можно где-то получить строки для локализации.

Comment: глянь это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412596/localize-done-button-of-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller

Comment: Ответ нашелся здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014406/how-to-localize-custom-done-button